# eclipse pde expandable section of code in editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, pde, expandable

I'm looking for a way to `implement` expandable section of code in an editor for an eclipse plugin. I've already extended the `CompilationUnitEditor` class but I don't know how to add expandable sections. 
Could anyone help me ??

Or at least address me to valid documentation with which I could understand the solution?

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor` is in an **internal** package so you are [breaking the rules](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by using it.

Comment: Ok. So where could i find another java editor to extend?